# Can we run resteasy on jdk 1.5

Tags: java, resteasy, java-5

I want to run Resteasy on jdk 1.5 but it requires 1.6 instead. [see this](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/2.0.1.GA/): look at jdk version in "depends on" category. Is there a way to run/compile the sources with jdk 5.? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can
It is Portable to any app-server/Tomcat that runs on JDK 5 or higher.

> **Features**

```
* Fully certified JAX-RS implementation
* Portable to any app-server/Tomcat that runs on JDK 5 or higher
* Embeddedable server implementation for junit testing
* Client framework that leverages JAX-RS annotations so that you can write HTTP clients easily (JAX-RS only defines server bindings)
* Client "Browser" cache. Supports HTTP 1.1 caching semantics including cache revalidation
* Server in-memory cache. Local response cache. Automatically handles ETag generation and cache revalidation
* Rich set of providers for: XML, JSON, YAML, Fastinfoset, Multipart, XOP, Atom, etc.
* JAXB marshalling into XML, JSON, Jackson, Fastinfoset, and Atom as well as wrappers for maps, arrays, lists, and sets of JAXB Objects.
* GZIP content-encoding. Automatic GZIP compression/decompression suppport in client and server frameworks
* Asynchronous HTTP (Comet) abstractions for JBoss Web, Tomcat 6, and Servlet 3.0
* Asynchronous Job Service.
* Rich interceptor model.
* EJB, Seam, Guice, Spring, and Spring MVC integration
```

Reference: http://jboss.org/resteasy  See OverView--> Features.

Comment: Well, this is not true anymore.. now in their website you could see it --> Portable to any app-server/Tomcat that runs on JDK 6 or higher

Answer (score 1):

The jars that you get from the site are compiled with Java 1.6 (at least the 2.1.0.GA release).   The key term here is "portable", which I'm interpreting to mean you have to recompile the project from scratch to get the 1.5 version.

Comment: So you mean I need to get all the corresponding source codes for Resteasy and then re-compile? if yes, where do I get the codes from?

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#Overview) says otherwise:

> Portable to any app-server/Tomcat that runs on JDK 5 or higher